# Docker cannot run angular container on different port that node express start

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, docker-compose, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to run angular app with ssr on docker.

My dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:10-alpine as build-stage
ENV PROD true
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app

RUN npm run build:ssr

# stage 2
FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /app
# Copy dependency definitions
COPY --from=build-stage /app/package.json /app

# Get all the code needed to run the app
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /app/dist

ADD ./build.js /app

EXPOSE 4200

CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "node build.js && npm run serve:ssr"]
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

    frontend:
      build:
        context: ../../frontend/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: "frontend"
      ports:
         - 4500:4200
      networks:
          - external-network

networks:
    external-network:
        external: true
```

Ok now when im trying get into localhost:4500 im getting error:

```
frontend    | 
frontend    | > frontend@0.0.3 serve:ssr /app
frontend    | > node --max_old_space_size=4096 dist/apps/frontend/server/server
frontend    |
frontend    | Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4200
frontend    | (node:26) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
frontend    | ERROR Failed to load the config file
frontend    | ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load the config file
frontend    |     at resolvePromise (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:1028:31)
frontend    |     at resolvePromise (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:985:17)
frontend    |     at /app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:1089:17
frontend    |     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:599:31)
frontend    |     at Object.onInvokeTask (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:192931:33)
frontend    |     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:598:60)
frontend    |     at Zone.runTask (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:371:47)
frontend    |     at drainMicroTaskQueue (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:777:35)
frontend    |     at ZoneTask.invokeTask (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:678:21)
frontend    |     at ZoneTask.invoke (/app/dist/apps/frontend/server/server.js:663:48)
frontend    |   rejection: 'Failed to load the config file',
frontend    |   promise:
frontend    |    ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
frontend    |      __zone_symbol__state: 0,
frontend    |      __zone_symbol__value: 'Failed to load the config file' },
frontend    |   zone:
frontend    |    Zone {
frontend    |      _parent:
frontend    |       Zone {
frontend    |         _parent: null,
frontend    |         _name: '<root>',
frontend    |         _properties: {},
frontend    |         _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate] },
frontend    |      _name: 'angular',
frontend    |      _properties: { isAngularZone: true },
frontend    |      _zoneDelegate:
frontend    |       ZoneDelegate {
frontend    |         _taskCounts: [Object],
frontend    |         zone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _parentDelegate: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _forkZS: null,
frontend    |         _forkDlgt: null,
frontend    |         _forkCurrZone: [Zone],
frontend    |         _interceptZS: null,
frontend    |         _interceptDlgt: null,
frontend    |         _interceptCurrZone: [Zone],
frontend    |         _invokeZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _invokeDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _invokeCurrZone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _handleErrorZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _handleErrorDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _handleErrorCurrZone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _scheduleTaskZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _scheduleTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _scheduleTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _invokeTaskZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _invokeTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _invokeTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _cancelTaskZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _cancelTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _cancelTaskCurrZone: [Circular],
frontend    |         _hasTaskZS: [Object],
frontend    |         _hasTaskDlgt: [ZoneDelegate],
frontend    |         _hasTaskDlgtOwner: [Circular],
frontend    |         _hasTaskCurrZone: [Circular] } },
frontend    |   task:
frontend    |    ZoneTask {
frontend    |      _zone:
frontend    |       Zone {
frontend    |         _parent: [Zone],
frontend    |         _name: 'angular',
frontend    |         _properties: [Object],
frontend    |         _zoneDelegate: [ZoneDelegate] },
frontend    |      runCount: 0,
frontend    |      _zoneDelegates: null,
frontend    |      _state: 'notScheduled',
frontend    |      type: 'microTask',
frontend    |      source: 'Promise.then',
frontend    |      data:
frontend    |       ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
frontend    |         __zone_symbol__state: 0,
frontend    |         __zone_symbol__value: 'Failed to load the config file' },
frontend    |      scheduleFn: undefined,
frontend    |      cancelFn: undefined,
frontend    |      callback: [Function],
frontend    |      invoke: [Function] } }
frontend    | Failed to load the config file
```

But why i can't run it on another port?

When i run my docker-compose like this:

```
version: "3.8"
services:

    frontend:
      build:
        context: ../../frontend/
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      container_name: "frontend"
      ports:
         - 4200:4200
      networks:
          - external-network

networks:
    external-network:
        external: true
```

Everything is running perfect.

Why i can only run app on default node express port?

Comment: What is the external network configuration? Should not work both from outside the docker network, due to limitation of serve to localhost (and outside the docker network you're not on localhost anymore). `npm run serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck` should be required..

Comment: There is no no special configuration i juz create network using docker network create external-network

Comment: I change configuration in docker file to: CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "node build.js && npm run serve:ssr --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck"] still same problem

Comment: Use ng serve - - port 4500, mapping with web apps is not working due to the fact how browsers fetch content. If you want to do so use proper hosting approaches..